# Zend Framework 2 Di creates class without parameters

Tags: dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I have the following code in config:

```
<?php
return array(
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(
            'alias' => array(
                'sms_message' => 'Sms\Message',
            ),
            'sms_message' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'from' => 'SENDER',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

And in Message.php class I have a setter (I dont want to use contructor):

```
/**
 * From
 * @var string
 */
protected $from;

/**
* @param string $from
*/
public function setFrom($from)
{
    $this->from = $from;
}
```

But when I try to load it I get unconfigured object:

```
var_dump($this->getLocator()->get('Sms\Message'));exit;

object(Sms\Message)[596]
    protected 'to' => null
    protected 'from' => null
    protected 'body' => null
```

How do I can make it work?

Comment: Have you tried this without using the alias but only the FQN? Afaik the 'alias' key must be at the same level as the 'instance' key for the configuration as well.

Comment: it actually at the same level. just badly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setter-injection you have to use the `injections` keyword:

```
array(        
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(
            'alias' => array(
                'sms_message' => 'Sms\Message'
            ),
            'Sms\Message' => array(
                'injections' => array(
                    'setFrom' => array(
                        'from' => 'SENDER'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

I'm not sure if the instance configuration is supposed to work with aliases. Better use the FQCN instead.

I also discovered that currently injections are not executed when requesting an alias while reproducing your example:

```
// The will call setFrom(...)
$di->get('Sms\Message);
// This will not call setFrom(...)
$di->get('sms_message');
```

I don't know if this behavior is intended or not. (I'll report this [test](https://github.com/fritz-gerneth/zf2/compare/test/di-alias-injection) which is currently [failing](http://travis-ci.org/#!/fritz-gerneth/zf2/builds/1753053))